# Get access to the right element in the Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, console

I am using the for-loop below:

```
console.log(a1); 
 for(var f = 0; f < a1.length; f++){

 b= a1[f];

console.log(b);............
```

My console shows me this:

```
  Array [ Array[6], Array[8] ] 
  Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ] 
  Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Now, the first Array line in the console is `console.log(a1)` and the other 2 Arrays are `console.log(b)`.

I want to get access to the whole first Array of `console.log(b)` only. 
I tried to use console.log(b[0]), but this shows me only the first objects including their properties of the 2 Arrays, but I want to see the full first Array with the 6 elements only on my console. Can someone help me to solve?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to work with the first array of objects, which is the first element of `a1`, so you need to loop through `a1[0]` which gives you the first array as wanted:

```
for(var f = 0; f < a1[0].length; f++) {
    var b = a1[0][f];
    console.log(b);
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunally this is not working with the code i use after that. Because when i use your solution then it gives me an error like "b.includes is not a function".  Is there any solution to keep the array b how it is and only change the loop?

Comment: That's because `b` is no longer an array. b is an *element* of the first array. Since `a1` is an array of arrays `a1[0]` is your first array and `a1[1]` is your second. But if you let us know what exactly it is you want to accomplish further in your code, we might be able to help.

Comment: @derick collin not part of your question => not part of the answer

Comment: @Botimoo, thanks for the help. The further code is just some styling of nodes in d3.js where I use the function `b.includes()`.